# Cannot get path from process vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]

I'm creating a program project like Task Manager
I encountered a problem obtaining the location of one or more programs. This error shows `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'`

This is what I use

```
Dim idProcess As Process
idProcess = Process.GetProcessById(id)
pathid = Path.GetDirectoryName(idProcess.MainModule.FileName)
Process.Start("explorer.exe", pathid)
```

For Example :
The program `AvastUI`64bit and `wsc_proxy`64bit they are in the same path, but I cannot open a path `wsc_proxy`
but I can open the program's location in the task manager

I did this to try to fix the problem but it didn't work

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

or

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me? I have already searched and tried 6 solutions none of them worked, I checked whether the program is protected or not and I downloaded other similar programs to the task manager and worked, I want to know how to solve this problem please

Comment: I ran your code on my machine and I get similar errors. I checked this site and it looks like he just skips processes with errors: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/439/how-to-list-all-windows-processes-and-their-attributes-task-manager-like-with-c-in-winforms